# PostgreSQL view-based query is not flattening as expected

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, view

I have a view but querying it is about 100x slower than running the view's query with the additional WHERE clause. Why is it not flattening and running at comparable speed? I can also see the issue when comparing EXPAIN ANALYZE output for both.

(The following queries are pseudo-queries)

View Query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW person AS
SELECT 
    name,
    student_id,
    teacher_id,
    enrollment_id
FROM
(
    (SELECT 
         CONCAT_WS(' ', name_first, name_last) as name,
         student_id as student_id,
         Null as teacher_id,
         enrollment_id
     FROM student
    )
     UNION  ALL

     (SELECT 
     full_name as name,
     Null as student_id,
     id as teacher_id,
     enrollment_id
     FROM teacher)
) as persons
```

If I run the above query with the addition of a where clause (`WHERE enrollment_id = 1`), I get blazing-fast results. If instead I run:
`SELECT * FROM person WHERE enrollment_id=1`, it takes much, much longer. My "student" table is very large.

Comment: What happens if you don't wrap the UNION? https://pastebin.com/kjGTSH3w

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I get an error: ```ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 12:         (SELECT 
                 ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
Time: 1.891 ms```

Comment: "(The following queries are pseudo-queries)"  Does that mean they don't actually exhibit the behavior in question?

Comment: @jjanes -- I cannot reveal proprietary information, so this query is an approximation (with different names) of the query I am running.

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question.  Once you create new tables with different names, and defined your view over them, do they still exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: Well, the suggestion I made does not use any sub-queries that would require an alias, so you clearly added things that I did not suggest. Most probably useless pairs of parentheses.

Comment: Please make sure that you show code that actually exhibits the problem. Please add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)` output for both queries.

Comment: @user7097722 - you can use www.depesz.com to obfuscate the plan of your real query - no need to reveal anything sensitive **and** those here trying to help you will have the information they need!